How to identify the rows of a df1 that have an element contained in a df2 in python?
I have two dataframes that I would like to compare, and I would need to know if the objects stored in df1 are also present in my df2.
However, objects of my df2 are longer because of many additional information.
As an example, my df1:
df1 = pandas.DataFrame(data = {'data1' : ['S10321Nr1.1', 'S10321Nr2.1', 'S10321Nr3.1', 'S10321Nr4.1']})
then, my df2:
df2 = pandas.DataFrame(data = {'data2' : ['HPAFII/Counts/S10323Nr1/HPAFII.S10323Nr1.1.genes.raw.csv.gz', 'HPAFII/Counts/S10323Nr1/HPAFII.S10323Nr1.2.genes.raw.csv.gz.md5sum', 'HPAFII/Counts/S10323Nr10/HPAFII.S10323Nr1.3.genes.raw.csv.gz', 'HPAFII/Counts/S10323Nr10/HPAFII.S10323Nr4.1.genes.raw.csv.gz.md5sum']})
Is there a way to get df1 rows for which the number in df1 is also present in df2?
I wish it returns a new column in df1 like:
df1 = pandas.DataFrame(data = {'data1' : ['S10321Nr1.1', 'S10321Nr2.1', 'S10321Nr3.1', 'S10321Nr4.1'], 'true-false' : ['True', 'False', 'False', 'True']})
I already tried with the following strategies, but it doesn't work properly (return nan):
df1["TrueFalse"] = df2['data_name'].apply(lambda x: 1 if any(i in x for i in df1) else 0)
df1['new_col'] = df1[~df1['data1'].isin(df2)]
Thanks!

Please add a [mre]. Add data as text, not as pictures. Please also share the expected output based on the samples for df1 and df2.

Cleaner solution using panda's str.contains instead of list comprehension:

df1["present_in_df2"] = df1.apply(
lambda row: any(df2['data2'].str.contains(row['data1'], regex=False)),
axis=1
)

The True if ... else False in the other answer is also not necessary, the statement already evaluates to a bool.
(Btw - the expected output you gave in your question is incorrect)

The following codes may solve your problems:
df1["indf2"] = df1.apply(
    lambda row: 1 if any(row["data1"] in i for i in df2["data2"]) else 0, 
    axis=1
)
# with 'df1.apply(..., axis=1)' statement will apply function to eacy row of df1
# 'for i in df2["data2"]' means we will get every row's string from df2["data2"], so we can use 'row["data1"] in i' to see if data of df1["data1"] presents in df2["data2"] column

